# undefined method `simple_nested_form_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-form-for

I'm getting this error when trying to use the nested_form Rails plugin, what's wrong?

I've set my Gem file to say `gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'`

I've installed the plugin (I'm using Rails 3.1) and I've restarted my server.

**Edit:** I also moved the nested_form.js to the /assets/javascript/ folder because loading it in the public folder gave me a Routing Error if I clicked on it in the source.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) installed for this to work.

Comment: Yes I have both `gem 'simple_form'
gem 'nested_form', :git => "https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git" ` any other suggestions?

Comment: Any other suggestions? Desperate for help on this

Comment: No other suggestions. I only went by what is in the readme. Try contacting the project owner.

Comment: Ah opening the form you need simple_nested_form_for...not inside the field_for area.